# List out the original IP Address of the host

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have following content in the file. I would like to print the IP address which is Under Name.

```
Server:     17.128.100.12
Address:    17.128.100.12#53
Name:   Testserver1
Address: 17.146.118.156
Server:     17.128.100.12
Address:    17.128.100.12#53
Name:   Testserver2
Address: 17.146.118.168
Server:     17.128.100.12
Address:    17.128.100.12#53
Name:   Testserver3
Address: 17.146.118.166
```

The output should look like:

```
17.146.118.156
17.146.118.168
17.146.118.166
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 grep ^Address my_file | grep -v "#" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: what will grep -v "#" | awk '{print $2}' do? How does these two commands work?

Also, is there a way, we can do this using sed?

Comment: I got how grep -v "#" and awk '{print $2}' works. But can it be done using sed?

Comment: `sed -n -e "/^Address/p" IP | sed -e "/#/d" | awk '{print $2}'` Those 2 `sed` commands can be combined in to one regex but my `sed` fu is not that strong to figure out how. But this works. I just tested on my machine

Comment: It was helpful. Also, i have another question. I have a file which comprises below content

Name=Sai

When i run the following query I’m able to fetch the desired result, But I could not sense how does the command work?

sed '/^\#/d' usernam|grep username|tail -n 1|sed -e 's/^.*=//'

Can you elaborate how does sed '/^\#/d' and sed -e 's/^.*=//' work? How does special characters function?

Comment: `^` is the beginning of line,  `d` is delete, and `s` is substitute. In the light of these you can figure what those two `sed` commands are doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` with like this:

```
 awk 'BEGIN {firstName=0;} /Name/ {firstName=1;} /Address/ {if(firstName) {print $NF}; firstName=0;}' <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777 -e 'print join "\n", <> =~ m/Name.*?Address:\s*([\d.]+)/gms;'
```

Uses a multi-line regex to match 'digits and dots', after an 'Address:' which is directly preceeded (Because `.*?` is nongreedy) by Name

Reads this from `<>` which is the magic file handle - reads either STDIN, or files specified, e.g.

```
perl -0777 -e 'print join "\n", <> =~ m/Name.*?Address:\s*([\d.]+)/gms;' somefile
```

Alternatively, set the record separator to 'Name':

```
perl -lne '$/="Name:"; /Address: ([\d\.]+)/ && print $1'
```

Because of the lack of `g` it only matches the first time in each 'record'.